# Getting parent names from a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:

```
{
    id: 15
    name: "Power",
    childCategories: [],
    parent: {
        id: 10,
        name: "Cables",
        parent: null,
        stockItems: []
    }
}
```

Ideally, what I would like to end up with is the following String structure:

```
Cables ⟶ Power
```

But being new to Javascript, I'm not sure how  I would achieve this. I'm assuming it would be through recursion.

Comment: So you have an array with one object with nested properties and you want to have an object: `{ Cables: 'Power' }`, or do you want to assign the string "Power" to a variable called `Cables`?

Comment: what is Cables?

Comment: @Andy - I've updated OP to make it a little clearer what I have. In total, I have one Object which has a parent array, which may have it's own parent array and so on. The "Root" parent is the one which has null in parent.

What I need is to take each parents name and apply it to a string in the reverse order. 

So let's take the above. If I were to just get the parent names I would end up with: ```Cables⟶Power```, However what I need is ```Power⟶Cables```. Does this make sense?

Comment: Only that you want a different output from your question :). You want `Cables⟶Power`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to "reverse" the way your data is structured ("children -> parents" to "parents -> children").

Your assumption about recursive function is right: in this example I tried to add more data, according to the description given.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    childCategories: [],
    id: 15,
    name: "Power",
    parent: {
        id: 10,
        name: "Cables",
        parent: null,
        stockItems: [],
    }
  },
  {
    childCategories: [],
    id: 9,
    name: "Gas",
    parent: {
        id: 20,
        name: "Pipes",
        parent: {
        id: 33,
          name: "Metal",
          parent: null,
          stockItems: [],
      },
        stockItems: [],
    }
  }
]


const res = []


for (const o of arr) {
  recursiveFunct(o)
}

function recursiveFunct(o) {
  if (o.parent) {
    let parent = o.parent
    delete o.parent
    parent.children = o
    recursiveFunct(parent)
  } else {
    res.push(o)
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each object passed into the recursive function `push` its `name` into into an array (`result`).

If the object has a parent property that isn't `null` pass the parent object back into the function along with `result`.

If the parent *is* null reverse the array and join it up with a "⟶".

```js
const obj = {
  id: 153,
  name: "Gold plated",
  childCategories: [],
  parent: {
    id: 15,
    name: "Power",
    childCategories: [],
    parent: {
      id: 10,
      name: "Cables",
      parent: null,
      stockItems: []
    }
  }
};

// Pass in the object, and initialise `result`
function getString(obj, result = []) {
  
  // Push each name into the array
  result.push(obj.name);
  
  // If the parent is `null` return the joined array
  // otherwise pass the parent object back into the 
  // function along with the result array
  if (!obj.parent) {
    return result.reverse().join(' ⟶ ');
  } else {
    return getString(obj.parent, result);
  }

}

console.log(getString(obj));
```